# Delay when using texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

There is a phenomenon that the brush tool is delayed by 0.5 seconds to paint the texture in the 3D view panel.

The more problematic thing is that the delay time increase. That means, the more I paint the texture, the slower it is.

However, this problem does not occurre in UV panel.

My working environment is as follows,

CPU: Rizen 1700x
RAM: 16 GB
Graphics card: GTX 1070 (CUDA1902)

Comment: difficult to say, does this happen just with that brush tool, while others are faster? is your model particularly heavy (although you have a very fast machine it seems)? does it happen on any other (simpler) model too?

Answer (score 1):

UV Image Editor will always be faster with paint because it isn't held back by projection effects like culling, cavity mask, etc. Painting in the 3d view needs to be done with small brushes for faster paint daubs, as large brush radius can cause a memory choke while waiting to project and calculate all the pixels to be affected by the paint stroke.

Also, a key factor here is how large your texture is and how many undo steps exist in your preferences. Decrease the undo steps or eliminate them altogether for the session and see if the memory spikes stop. The size of the texture and the bit depth can cause some issues with painting using projection in the 3d view, but you will see that the UV Image Editor handles them much easier.

The key difference in these two options for paint is that the UV Image Editor is one texture at a time (display) but the 3d view can display all or one (GLSL/Material Draw mode vs. Multitexture) and you can use both to their advantage to get the best effects.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I haven't seen answered in posts regarding texture painting is changing the textures slots from "material" to "single image", then you choose the texture you want to work into and the UV coordinates to use, this made painting actually possible.